# The component handles the form submission by calling its own callback? What does calling its own callback mean in this context?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am learning about flux architecture for reactjs, while reading this article: https://medium.com/brigade-engineering/what-is-the-flux-application-architecture-b57ebca85b9e

I can not seem to get what does the author means by "component handles the form submission by calling its own callback" in following context:

```
// Saving a new ToDo calls the '_onSave' callback

var Header = React.createClass({

  /**
   * @return {object}
   */
  render: function() {
    return (
      <header id="header">
        <h1>todos</h1>
        <TodoTextInput
          id="new-todo"
          placeholder="What needs to be done?"
          onSave={this._onSave}
        />
      </header>
    );
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

The term "callback" may be the incorrect here, but I think he just means that he's passing a function defined in the `Header` class, `this._onSave` to a child component `TodoTextInput` so that when `TodoTextInput` is submitted, the function inside `Header` is called and therefore `TodoTextInput` doesn't have to know about it.